# Using MonoDevelop Smart Menu

Tags: c#, .net, monodevelop

First off, apologies if this is a complete noob question which could easily be resolved by common sense, but I'm really not getting some things here.

I've been searching all over to figure this out (even posting on Mono Forums without any luck), and haven't quite found a thing. So, does anyone know what version of .NET MonoDevelop comes with? Also, while it implies that Generics and Type references, etc. can be used, I still find that hard to believe, as they don't show up in the code completion list.

For example, when I try to bring up List, the code completion list will show me something like "SortedList", as an option I can select, yet won't bring up just "List." The same thing with "Type", "Object", or just any *type* reference for that matter! On top of that, it won't log the variables I've created either.

Could someone tell me if I need to install something extra? I'm running the latest stable version of Mono, here, and I'm just really confused.

Comment: Have you inserted using System.Collections; and using System.Collections.Generic at the beginning of your class?

Comment: Yup. That hasn't been a problem at all.

Comment: I mean, unless they just copied Java development frameworks and then converted them to C#, organizing the assemblies as required, I really don't see how they could truly "open source" .NET. On top of that, it appears that the Java Collections assembly doesn't have a "List<T>" option, either, yet holds a "LinkedList<T>" option, which is what I see in my code completion menu when I try to type *List<T>* - but, of course, no List<T> itself option is shown.

Comment: @Holland, I am really confused about your last comment. Maybe I am missing something big, or didn't understand your question, but I don't see the relation among your question, Java and open sourcing .NET. About your initial question: Monodevelop does not come with any mono vm, you have to download it separatedly. Here Monodevelop 2.4.2.1 works as exepected (i.e., with the appropriate using's, it shows List<> as an option after you type "list"). I'm using mono 2.8.2.

Comment: @Baltasarq, so, you're saying this should work fine out of the box? I'm using Microsoft.CSharp; System.Collections; System.Collections.Generic; System.Collections.Specialization, etc. and nothing is showing how it should. If this isn't supposed to be compatible out of the box, then where can I download it seperately?

Comment: Oh, and about Java and open sourcing .NET: I read a Java file which included some implementations of a Java library, and what I saw displayed on my code completion menu was the same as what was shown in the Java document. It made me wonder if, since JAva is similar to C#, the Mono developers simply ported much of the Java framework to C# and simply renamed/reimplemented it to a C# understanding. I have no idea, it's just that all I see here seems to be Java, when in fact I'm using C# code. I know that C# is supposed to be like Java with different options and libraries added ontop of what

Comment: @Baltasarq ...Java provides, so it's just a curious question is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Mono vm, compilers, etc., from here:

http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html